# KDE Plasma auto-hide panel, show when mouse touches screen edge with force

Tags: kde, panel, plasma, plasma-5, autohide

Is there any possibility to configure an auto-hiding panel in a way it does only show when you touch the screen edge with a certain amount of force, so that you don't accidentally show it when touching the edge (when closing tabs in Chrome, for instance)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I see no such setting for the Plasma panel. You could put the hiding panel to the bottom for example, an area that you normally do not touch very often. I find a hiding panel in the upper area very impractical, as it covers the windows border (which I need always visible for its buttons and for the 'close on middle-click' setting).  You could take a look at the Latte Dock (`latte-dock`) which is meant as an alternative to the default panels, but even there I see only a delay setting.

Comment: I'm using Latte Dock at the bottom edge of my screen and a default panel with handy widgets (wi-fi, bluetooth, calculator, dictionary, time) at top - do you know any possibility how I could migrate those widgets to the Latte Dock?

Comment: Plasma widgets are supported by the Late dock. Right click it and add widgets. I think if you right-click and change layouts you could find layouts that already have some widgets like the systray. More layouts [here](https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/417/)

Comment: I see no need for the latte dock, it is buggy and the panel can do the same things. What I use is a non-hiding upper panel for global menus (like in ubuntu proper) and the task manager and a hiding bottom panel for launchers, systray etc. But I found some tips on Latte [here](https://github.com/psifidotos/Latte-Dock/wiki/Tips-&-Tricks)

Comment: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=267277

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no such setting in KDE Plasma, it only supports checking if the mouse has touched the panel that has auto-hide, and if so, shows it:

```
else if (m_containsMouse) {
    autoHide = false;
```

Via [source mirror on GitHub](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-workspace/blob/cc8d3e7751859b703e09984d149268e0564a0124/shell/panelview.cpp#L620) for `plasma-workspace` in file `panelview.cpp`